# Update values by another column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need a query to:

Copy from database player, table item_proto_0, column locale_name

Paste to database player, table item_proto, column locale_name

**But:**

Just paste if has the same colum vnum

**I've tried:**

```
UPDATE item_proto.locale_name 
SET item_proto_0.locale_name 
WHERE item_proto_0.vnum=item_proto.vnum
```

Comment: Please avoid using uppercase for emphasis, especially when asking about SQL where it actually has a meaning other than shouting.

Comment: Is VNUM a primary key?  If not, do the tables have a different primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE item_proto AS ip
    INNER JOIN item_proto_0 ip0 ON ip.vnum = ip0.vnum
SET locale_name = ip0.locale_name
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM item_proto ip
    INNER JOIN item_proto_0 ip0 ON ip.vnum = ip0.vnum' at line 3:

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE item_proto P1
    JOIN item_proto_0 P2
       ON P1.vnum = P2.vnum
SET P1.locale_name = P2.locale_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run this sql query this should do the needful

```
UPDATE item_proto
inner join item_proto_0 on item_proto.vnum = item_proto_0.vnum
SET item_proto.locale_name = item_proto_0.locale_name
```